# Como obtener la fecha en php

Tags: php

Buenas tardes, resulta que tengo una fecha en php la cual funciona pero cuando son mas de las  6 pm pasa al otro dia este el el codigo.

```
$fech = date("Y-m-d");
```

por ejemplo hoy es 20 y ya me sale 21 en bogota, espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: ¿Es un servidor en local o remoto? ¿Qué hora tiene el servidor?

Comment: las dos local y remoto y me sucede lo mismo

Comment: Seguramente es porque estás recibiendo la fecha en UTC. ¿Has probado a poner tu zona horaria con `date_default_timezone_set`?

Comment: ya lo solucione con esto muchas gracias.  date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");

Comment: Perfecto! Ponlo como respuesta para que pueda servir de ayuda a otros usuarios, y así te doy un +1 ya de paso :)

Answer (score 3):

El problema era que no tenía la zona horaria para Bogotá. Para definir la zona horaria se puede usar [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), en mi caso:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción sería hacerlo mediante un objeto [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php), indicando que quieres un `TimeZone` específico para ese objeto.

Trabajar con objetos es mucho más flexible (por ejemplo en el caso de necesitar trabajar con objetos fecha de diferentes zonas). Y tiene la ventaja de que el objeto guarda otro tipo de información que puede serte útil más adelante. Los cálculos también se simplifican, por ejemplo si necesitas calcular diferencias entre fechas, etc.

El objeto se crearía así:

```
$fecha = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Bogota'));
```

Y para imprimirlo:

```
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
```

Si haces un `var_dump` de ese objeto fecha, verás todo lo que hay en él:

```
var_dump($fecha);
```

El resultado sería:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-01-20 21:05:30.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(14) "America/Bogota"
}
```

Supongamos que más adelante tú quieres saber el `TimeZone` de ese objeto:

```
echo $fecha->getTimezone()->getName();
```

Imprimirá:

```
America/Bogota
```

Como puedes ver, trabajar con objetos te abre un amplio abanico de posibilidades.

---

Veamos un código de prueba con lo dicho anteriormente, y usando otros `TimeZone`.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/UFBDA56726)**</kbd>

**❯ Código:**

```
$fecha = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Bogota'));
printFechaZone($fecha);

$fecha = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));
printFechaZone($fecha);

$fecha = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
printFechaZone($fecha);

$fecha = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
printFechaZone($fecha);

$fecha = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Africa/Luanda'));
printFechaZone($fecha);

function printFechaZone($miFecha){
    echo 'Zona: '.$miFecha->getTimezone()->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Fecha-Hora: '.$miFecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**❯ Resultado:**

```
Zona: America/Bogota
Fecha-Hora: 2018-01-20 21:17:12

Zona: Australia/Sydney
Fecha-Hora: 2018-01-21 13:17:12

Zona: Europe/Madrid
Fecha-Hora: 2018-01-21 03:17:12

Zona: Asia/Calcutta
Fecha-Hora: 2018-01-21 07:47:12

Zona: Africa/Luanda
Fecha-Hora: 2018-01-21 03:17:12
```